# MuiAutocomplete returns Converting circular structure to JSON error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried on using Material UI Autocomplete component. There are two types of autocomplete components: single option select as well as multiple options select.

The single option select works like a charm. However, the multiple one returns `Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Object' |     property '_context' -> object with constructor 'Object' --- property 'Provider' closes the circle TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Object' |     property '_context' -> object with constructor 'Object'` error. This doesn't make any sense for me since I am giving this type of structure for the options property:

```
[
 {
  id: 1, label: 'one'
 },
 {
  id: 2, label: 'two'
 }
]
```

I can assure, that the same options list works perfectly with single option select MuiAutocomplete component.

Versions I use:

```
React 18.2.0

@mui/material 5.14.1

@emotion/react 11.11.1

@emotion/styled 11.11.0
```

Comment: Please provide your code or reproduce the problem in codesandbox.